# Get Product/Services->pricing data on WHMCS to PHP

Tags: php, api, whmcs

i've problem to get value from WHMCS pricing, i need to take that value to set on my php page:
[WHMCS Pricing picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSkqa.png)

I've tried to solve for the problem through the internet but i got nothing, what i looking for is to set the value like this:
[PHP page result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZS9E.png)
*i just set static value on this picture

Anyone have any idea? Thanks for ur help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check [Data Feeds](https://docs.whmcs.com/Data_Feeds), to output you pricing on your front-page.